# How to get a changed value from dynamic control after postback C#

Tags: c#, dynamic, controls, viewstate, placeholder

I recently created a control which will create a dynamic control into a place holder so in order to retain this control, I stored it into viewstate and then in the postback I recreated it. Actually it's working but how can I save the new changed value from this control because after postback is giving me the same value.

The property to keep in viewstate the control

```
    public Control MyControl
    {
        get
        {
            return (Control)ViewState["MyControl"] ?? null;
        }
        set
        {
            this.ViewState["MyControl"] = value;
        }
    }
```

Then a Method that will create the control when I click on a Edit Button in order to change from Literal to a TextBox.

```
    private void CreateControl()
    {
        Control ctrl = new TextBox();
        this.MyControl = ctrl;
        this.BindValue(ctrl); //Bind the value from DB Text = "1"
        this.placeHolder.Controls.Add(ctrl);
    }
```

Then the control will appear with the value of "1" and then I changed to "2" then click a button to save the changes

```
    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        string value = String.Empty;
        Control ctrl = this.MyControl;
        if (ctrl is TextBox)
        {
            //I want here the value of 2 but I get 1 again
            value = ((TextBox)ctrl).Text;
        }
        //Save operation into DB
    }
```

**----- EDIT -----**

The only thing that I needed was to recreate the objects on the load event as Dmytro Rudenko said before. More than init or not that fixed my issue. I didn't need the viewstate anymore

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
            Control ctrl = this.CreateControl();
            this.placeHolder.Controls.Add(ctrl);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create your dynamic control in `Page_Init` method on every `postback`. In this case created control may restore its viewstate successfully.

1. add hidden field to the form:

   ```
   <input type="hidden" name="recreate" value='<%= ViewBag["recreate"] %>' />
   ```
2. add control

   ```
   private void CreateControl()
     {
       Control ctrl = new TextBox();
       this.DynamicControl = ctrl;
       this.BindValue(ctrl); //Bind the value from DB Text = "1"
       this.placeHolder.Controls.Add(ctrl);
       ViewBag["recreate"] = "1";
     }
   ```
3. Recreate control

   ```
   protected Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (Request.Form["recreate"] != null && Request.Form["recreate"] == "1")
       {
          CreateControl();
       }    
     }
   ```

Comment: In fact, the control creation and viewstate storage is when I click on a Edit Button in order to change from a literal to textbox

Comment: you may add some indicator for creating your control as html hidden field and check this hidden field value in Request.From collection in Page_Init for recreating your control.

Comment: Can you post an example. How can I store the changed value from dynamic control into the hidden without postback. Javascript? there are many types of control.

Comment: I add some example in the answer

Comment: I'm so sorry if I was not clear. I will always get the value = "1" the thing is that once the page was rendered with textbox control and the value = "1" from DB then someone type with the keyboard the new value as "2". I want to store or preserve the new value 2 not 1.

Comment: ViewBag["recreate"] and Request.Form["recreate"] just a markers that you have to recreate your control, nothing more. You may change "1" value for theirs to the "true" for example. This "1" is not your '!" from textbox inside your control.

Answer (score 0):

The value is not being saved in the ViewState.  When ever the btnSave button is clicked, the page goes through re-adding the control to the page, BEFORE, the save button event fires.  So, your CreateControl() method is firing before the btnSave event, and the "1" value is being reloaded into the newly created control.  In your method, you'll need to differentiate when you want that value to be bound to the control, either with !IsPostback or by some other means that is necessary to your application.

I've used a variable depicting what was causing the postback; if the postback was based on a menu click, then, the page re-adds all of the controls and then binds the appropriate controls to the DB.  If the postback was caused by a dropdown, or grid view page, then the page re-adds he controls but, does not bind them to the DB, as to persist their input values. But, there are different ways of doing this, and, again, it is dependent on your application needs.